# What does 'very robust through email gateways' means in Content-Type multipart header?

Tags: http-headers, multipartform-data, multipart

I'm studying about `Content-Type` header and in *multipart* section, I could find this sentence from developer.mozilla([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type)).

**boundary**

For multipart entities the boundary directive is required, which consists of 1 to 70 characters from a set of characters known to be **very robust through email gateways**, and not ending with white space. It is used to encapsulate...

As I know, "email gateway" is a type of email server that protects server. And I cannot understand what does robust through email gateway means. What does it mean?

Comment: Note that MDN is just a wiki, not an authoritative source. There is a [standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046#section-5) that you can look to to understand these issues.